# Browser goes forward two steps with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

I'm currently making a gallery with JavaScript. I want to create a custom history entry, so that the enduser can click the history back for closing a big-picture overlay.

My window.onpopstate looks like this:

```
   function stateChange(event){
    let state = event.state;
    console.log(state);
    if(state !== null){
        if(state.show){
            showOverlay(state.obj);
        }else{            
            hideOverlay();
        }
    }else{
        hideOverlay();
    }
}
```

And my eventListener for the pictures:

```
    let state = {show: true, obj: itemLinks[i].dataset.file};
    history.pushState(state, '');
```

The Problem is, that my console fires **one** null following after **one** click on a picture. But, when I then go back in the history it shows the state object. If I go back another time, I get the null, where I had started.

-- EDIT --

More of my code:

```
for (let i = 0, len = itemLinks.length; i < len; i++) {
    itemLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        let state = {show: true, obj: itemLinks[i].dataset.file};
        history.pushState(state, '');
    });
}
overlay.addEventListener('click', clickOverlay)
window.onpopstate = stateChange;
```

And:

```
let itemLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('item-link');

let overlay = document.getElementById('gallery-overlay');
let overlayImg = document.getElementById('gallery-overlay-img');    

function showOverlay(src){
    overlayImg.src = src;
    overlay.classList.add('gallery-overlay__show');
}

function hideOverlay(){
    overlay.classList.remove('gallery-overlay__show');
}

function clickOverlay(){
    history.back();
}
```

Comment: Can you show complete example? Maybe you bind event multiple times?

Comment: Thank you. Take a look at my edit please.

Comment: What type of element are your `item-link`s?  Anchor tags might be causing one navigation, then your JS causes another?

Comment: Thank you! It is a `<a>` element, wich does the trouble...!

Comment: You can keep them as `<a>` tags (for browser styling, hover cursor, etc) if you'd like, you'll just need to use the `event.preventDefault()` function.  I can write a full answer on that if you'd like.

Comment: I've already changed it to a `<span>` element and styled it with css. Thank you very much. For other people it would be quit helpfull, if you write am anwer, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the elements being clicked to trigger the navigation were `<a>` tags, which will trigger a navigation event if they are clicked and their `href` attribute is set.

To avoid this you can change the element from an `<a>` tag to something else like `<span>` or an inline `<div>`, but this can bring usability concerns if your page ever needs to be navigable without a mouse.  A more robust solution is to prevent the click event from causing navigation, using `event.preventDefault()`:

```
let itemLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('item-link');

for (let link of itemLinks) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // Keep the <a> tag from triggering the default navigation
    event.preventDefault();

    // Push our own state navigation
    let state = {show: true, obj: link.dataset.file};
    history.pushState(state, '');
  });
}
```

This way you still keep all of the beneficial behavior of `<a>` tags without the pesky extra navigation event.